# Changing debuging environment in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, path

In my C++ microsoft visual studio 2010 project, I would like to add a directory to search the dlls while running my project application.
In Configuration properties > Debugging > Environment
I can't change the default value:
PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin%3b$(PATH)
I am trying to set this value: PATH=C:\my\path\dll;$(QTDIR)\bin%3b$(PATH)
Then I apply the change, run my project and the value come back to
PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin%3b$(PATH)

Anyone know how I could do that properly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to recompile before changes are applied. Consider as well to check if you have chosen the correct configuration and platform.

Comment: Well the changes are applied but disappear when I recompile or launch the application. Also I am sure about the right configuration and platform. I chagned others options. But just this one is not taken into account.

Comment: Sounds strange. Do you use any subversion clients?

Comment: No but I have the qt add-in installed. I think it's this add-on that reset the PATH variable. I will investigate.

Comment: Could be..that means you would have to change it in control panel-> environment variables probably.